# Overlapping Content (code included)

Tags: html, css

This might be a little bulky,

Basically, I like how I have laid out this page, but when I resize the window, since I used position: relative, a lot of the elements overlap once the window is small enough. Additionally, it's usually standard (based on websites I have visited) that when resizing, elements are fixed and that you'd just have to scroll to get to the elements that are off screen, but in this case I have everything scaling with the window size. I am not sure if elements scaling with the screen are a good or bad design, however I would like to fix the overlapping issue. And if it is poor design to scale the elements, I would appreciate any suggestions as to achieving the same result with no scaling.

I have replaced most of the background content with solid colors. Also, I understand that a lot of what I may have already and will do in the future may be shortened with JavaScript, however I still need to learn it :)

Any suggestions regarding structure of classes, headers, tags etc. would be very helpful, this is only my second day of html/css. I am currently looking for online resources regarding these topics!

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body {
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

h1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 3vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5vh;
  right: 1.5vw;
}

#background-div {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: ease-in 0.3s;
}

#background2-div {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: ease-in 0.3s;
}

#intro .button {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  width: 20vw;
  height: 25vh;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}

.button.english {
  background-image: url('../images/uk_flag.png');
  left: 15vw;
}

.button.portuguese {
  background-image: url('../images/angola_flag.png');
  right: 15vw;
}

.button.english div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 48%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  color: white;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

.button.portuguese div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 49%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  color: white;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
}

#welcome .button {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  background-position: center center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 25vh;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  max-height: 80px;
  max-width: 20vw;
}

.button.buy {
  left: 15vw;
}

.button.sell {
  right: 15vw;
}

.button.buy div,
.button.sell div {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 4vw;
}

#intro .button:hover,
#welcome .button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  border-color: white;
}

.button.buy:hover~#background-div {
  opacity: 1;
  border-color: white;
  transition: ease-out 0.7s;
}

.button.sell:hover~#background2-div {
  opacity: 1;
  border-color: white;
  transition: ease-out 0.7s;
}

#videoback {
  position: fixed;
  top: -64px;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>AB</title>
  <link href="styles/intro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link href="welcome.html" rel="alternate" hreflang="en" />
  <link href="welcome_pt.html" rel="alternate" hreflang="pt" />
</head>

<body id="welcome">

  <a href="home.html" class="button buy" hreflang="en">
    <div>Buy</div>
  </a>

  <a href="apply.html" class="button sell" hreflang="en">
    <div>Sell</div>
  </a>

  <div id="background-div"></div>

  <div id="background2-div"></div>

  <video autoplay muted loop id="videoback">
   <source src="videos/blessings.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>


  <footer>
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="about.html" hreflang="en">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html" hreflang="en">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- Scripts -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you can solve your problem using bootstrap:

Link it in your html as such: 
`link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Use bootstrap to define rows and their column size:

```
<!-- this is necessary container to contain all your rows
note that you can have multiple containers per website, or even within
each other -->

<div class="container">
<!-- elements that will be displayed next to each other -->
  <div class="row">
<!-- two elements that will divide the row by half until MD size: >=992px -->
    <div class="col-md-6">content</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
<!-- three elements that will always be shown next to each other-->
    <div class="col-xs-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">content</div>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

Learn more about bootstrap:

- [quick tutorial for your needs](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)
- [Get started with bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)